# "My Places" in Google Maps

Tags: google-maps-navigation, google-apps

I want to mark "My Places" from my Android tablet but can't find the option in Google Maps. Are there any alternative apps? If possible, how can I edit my earlier marked places and / or find their longitude and latitude?

Comment: If you long place on a location you can click the popup on the bottom of the map with the address then click "Save" which has a big Star Icon above it. What do you mean "option to find longitude and latitude" are you trying to write an app or what?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with [google maps engine](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.m4b) ?